# Python variables

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a basic program that will generate a number based on variables entered by the user. The formula is

```
a = b / (c * d)
```

This is a formula for finding specific heat, whereas `b=energy`, `c=mass`, and `d= change in temperature`.

So my problem is that I'm not making this program for myself, otherwise I could just assign each variable a number- like:

```
b= 1200
c= 13
d= 2
```

And then do `a = a = b / (c * d)`.

My goal though, is to create a program for others who don't already know the formula- so that they can simply enter the numbers themselves. Example- I want `b = X`. `X` is the number entered by the user of the program. However, I have to define `X` as a variable first- I want it to be unknown- or based on what a person enters. I don't want `b`, `c`, or `d` to have assigned values. It's a very basic scripting process I know, but I'm new to Python.

Comment: +1 not a difficult question...but it doesnt deserve downvotes for being simple.

Answer (score 6):

I think you want something like this:

```
b = float(raw_input("Energy? "))
c = float(raw_input("Mass? "))
d = float(raw_input("Change in temperature? "))

print "Specific heat: %f" % (b / (c * d))
```

- raw_input() prompts the user and returns the inputted value
- float() converts the value to a float (if possible; if not, this will throw an exception and terminate the program)
- the "%f" in the last line formats the argument as a floating-point value, where "the argument" is the value of the expression following the % outside of the string (i.e. '(b / (c * d))')

Comment: Of course it's even better if we wrap that in some nice exception handling:  

    def getNum(prompt="Enter a number: "):
        result = None
        while result is None:
            try:
                result = float(raw_input(prompt))
            except ValueError:
                print "Couldn't parse that. Please try again."
            else:
                break
         return result

Answer (score 4):

The most simple approach is to precede the formula with the fragment

```
b = input("Enter b:")
c = input("Enter c:")
d = input("Enter d:")
```

A few things to note:

- this will require console IO, so you best start the script from a console
- input() causes the string entered to be eval()'ed, meaning that it gets processes as if it was a Python expression. This is useful for numbers, but may have confusing side effects; consider using `raw_input()`, along with `float()` instead.

Comment: It's extremely wise to warn novices to Python that `input()` is dangerous in Python 2.x and earlier.  In Python3 they've finally fixed that, but it was a long standing wart int he language (from when Guido conceived of it from one which was focused on teaching programming).  Python < 3 performs an *evaluation* of `input()` values.  It's the equivalent of `eval(input())` in Python 3.x.

Students should be warned to use `raw_input()` or even to start their code with `input = raw_input` to re-name them function before it's used in their code.

Answer (score 0):

```
b = float(raw_input("Please enter a value: "))
a = b / (c*d)
print a
```

`raw_input()` prompts the user for input, assuming you're running this in the console

`float()` attempts to convert the parameter (in this case, the user input) to a float.
the rest of it should be pretty straightforward.

Give that a try.  Welcome to Python :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried this and I know the actual script itself must work. My problem is that when I enter 
b = float(raw_input("Enter a value for energy: "))

I end up with:
b = float(raw_input("Enter a value for energy: "))
Enter a value for energy:

So I can't actually put anything there or it will assign B the variable of whatever I put. I have a feeling I have to put something at the beginning of my script recognizing it as a program or something. Sorry for my ignorance, once again I am very new to Python. Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: @Jordan: Your comment makes no sense at all.  Please rewrite it so it makes sense and update your question with whatever your *real* problem is.

Answer (score 0):

this is a really simple way to do it and easy to understand

```
b= float(raw_input("Enter the energy"))
c= float(raw_input("Enter the mass"))
d= float(raw_input("Enter change in temperature"))

a = b / (c * d)
print a
```